# The number of integral values of $'a'$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a\neq 0$. The number of integral values of 'a' so that the equation $a^2|a + x| + |a^2x + 1| = |a^3 - 1|$ has a unique solution is.

Comment: On MathSE, we'd like to see effort. What have you tried?

Comment: I was using triangle inequality to solve this problem.